# Degradeable jquery ajax forms with PHP - Code Repetition

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo, graceful-degradation

Assuming I have a form which I wish to submit. I have built it and the form `action=""`. As such, I can access the posted data via `if(isset($_POST['something']))`

EXAMPLE form.php (CODE NOT CHECKED AND JUST TO ILLUSTRATE POINT):

```
<?php
    $result = '';

    if (isset($_POST['something']) {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE Name = :name';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['something']);   
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="something" />
    <input type="submit" value="post" />
</form>

<div id="result">
    <pre>
    <?php echo $result; ?>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Now I wish to process the form with jquery/js if the user has got js enabled.

I know how to do this. However I have a problem with database access e.g. having the same query run in 2 php files. One in my original form page which is utilised when js it turned off and returns an associative array of data. I then have an ajaxData.php which returns json but is basically the same sql query.

EXAMPLE AJAXDATA.php

```
<?php
    $result = '';

    if (isset($_POST['something']) {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE Name = :name';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['something']);   
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    

    echo json_encode($result);
    }

?>
```

This is inefficient in my opinion because I am writing the same code, same data access etc... twice - once for form.php and once for ajaxdata.php.

How should I structure my forms/files so that ajax uses the same database access & sql code as the normal form submit?

Answer (score 1):

For html change
Add `onSubmit` event to handle `js` enable/disable

```
     <form action="" method="post" onSubmit="return process_ajax();">
       <input type="text" name="something" />
       <input type="submit" value="post" />
     </form>
```

in `precess_ajax()` return false so that form will not be submitted, and if `js` is disabled form will be submitted. All parameters must be same as if form posted.
Send an extra parameter in `AJAX` say `ajaxForm` to test on server side if post is by form or `AJAX`

Now for server side PHP code
Check for the extra paratmeter `ajaxForm` if it is set or have value that you sent in `AJAX`
send `JSON` response else send HTML page.
Your code will look like this

```
      if (isset($_POST['something']){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE Name = :name';
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
        $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['something']);   
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
        if(isset($_POST['ajaxForm'])){
          //send JSON response
        }
        else{
          //show html page here
        }   
      }

    ?>
```